# batch_input_shape tuple on Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following feature vector that consists in a single feature for each sample and 32 samples at total:

X = [[0.1], [0.12], [0.3] ... [0.10]]

and a label vector that consists of binary values

Y = [0, 1, 0 , 0, .... 1] (with 32 samples as well)

I'm trying to use Keras LSTM to predict the next value of the sequence based on a new entry. 
What I can't figure out is what the "batch_input_shape" tuple means for instance:

```
 model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(?, ?, ?), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
```

According to [this](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) article the first one is the batch size, but what about the other two? Are they the number of features for each sample and the number of samples? 
What should be the value of batch_size in this case?

At the moment receiving the error message:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)
```

Edit: Here is the model declaration:

```
def create_lstm(batch_size, n_samples, neurons, dropout):
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_size=batch_size, input_shape=(n_samples, 1), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Comment: Can you show your whole Sequential model you are defining?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm going to edit the post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) Keras Sequential Model guide on "stateful" LSTM (at the very bottom), we can see what those three elements mean:

> Expected input batch shape: (**batch_size**, **timesteps**, **data_dim**).
>   Note that we have to provide the full batch_input_shape since the network is **stateful**.
>   the sample of index i in batch k is the follow-up for the sample i in batch k-1.

The first one as you already discovered is the **size of the batches** to be used during training. How much you should chose depends in part on your specific problem, but mostly is given by the *size of your dataset*. If you specify a batch size of `x` and your dataset contains `N` samples, during training your data will be split in `N/x` groups (batches) of size `x` each.

Therefore, you probably want your batch size to be **smaller than the size of your dataset**. There is no unique value, but you want it to be proportionally smaller (say one or two orders) than all your data. Some people prefer to use powers of 2 (32, 128, etc.) as their batch sizes. It is also possible in some cases to not use batches at all, and train with all your data at once (although not necessarily better).

The other two values are the **timesteps** (the size of your temporal dimension) or "frames" each sample sequence has, and the **data dimension** (that is, the size of your data vector on each timestep).

For example, say your input sequences look like `X = [[0.54, 0.3], [0.11, 0.2], [0.37, 0.81]]`. We can see that this sequence has a *timestep* of `3` and a *data_dim* of `2`.

So, the `ValueError` you are getting is most probably due to this (the error even hints that it expected 3 dims). Also, make sure your array is a Numpy Array.

As a last comment, given that you say you have 32 samples total (that is your whole dataset contains 32 samples) I consider is too few data to be using batches; usually the minimum batch size I have seen is 32, so consider obtaining more data before trying to use batch training. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I have a bigger dataset but I trying to use a simple example first. So I get what you said but since I getting a error saying the API expects a 3 dimensional array, I need at least 3 metrics(features) for the model to work?

Comment: No problem, consider upvoting if you found it useful. Regarding the error, like I explained on the answer. Say you want to use batch of `32`, and that your data looks like `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` (thus shape `(3, 2)`). Then, you should have `batch_input_shape=(32, 3, 2)`. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Also I suggest you be careful when using the term "metrics" (usually a performance value we are interested in) as it is not the same as "features" (the elements that make your feature vector of your samples) and they may be confusing to use together :)

Comment: Glad I could help @Ricky :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus @DarkCygnus also a quick question in my case I have my input shape as (798,3) so my `batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 3)` where 1 = no.of batches,1=timestep and 3 my dimension,but it seems wrong

Comment: @Ricky same case as Andre, if your shape is `(798,3)` (798 timesteps of 3d data vectors) it should be `batch_input_shape=(32, 798, 3)`, assuming a batch size of 32.